# Can't load mod_wsgi compiled for Python 3

Tags: linux, apache, mod-wsgi, python-3.5

I'm on CentOS and trying to configure Apache to use mod_wsgi compiled against Anaconda Python 3.5. Compiling mod_wsgi *seems* to go OK:

```
sudo yum install httpd-devel
sudo ./configure --with-python=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
sudo make

ls -l /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 702205 Mar  2 23:12 /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

But when I start the web server it can't seem to find its libraries:

```
sudo service httpd start
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 221 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf: Cannot load
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`libpython3.5m.so.1.0` is definitely in `/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib`, so I suppose the `mod_wsgi.so` module doesn't know where to look for it. Yet the mod_wsgi `config.status` seems to confirm that

```
S["LDFLAGS"]=" -L/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib -L/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m "
```

so I'm at a loss... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: OK, thanks to @mata, I think I've compiled mod_wsgi against the correct libraries. But now the server logs just fill up with the same repeated message:

```
Current thread 0x00007f60d68d07e0 (most recent call first):
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

So I'm guessing apache is looking in the wrong place for the python libraries. The `00-wsgi.conf` file giving all the trouble reads:

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/anaconda/anaconda3
WSGIPythonPath /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

so I thought (from what I've read on other threads about this) that I'd told it where to look for my Python install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the library `libpython3.5m.so.1.0` can't be found at runtime because the directory `/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib` is not a place where the dynamic linker would look for it.

You can try to rebuild mod_wsgi using:

```
./configure LDFLAGS='-Wl,-rpath=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib' --with-python=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/python
```

That will save the library path within the generated binary.

The other option would be to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable for the apache process, which is not really a good method.
Or add the directory /opt/anaconda/anaconda3/lib to the library search path using a conf file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, that would be a global setting tough. See [`man ld-linux`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) for more info.

Also, don't forget to correctly set the `WSGIPythonHome` directive in your config file.

---

edit:

I've done some experimenting and I could reproduce your second error message when the `python3` binary is not found on the `PATH`.
In that case it seems setting the `WSGIPythonHome` directive is not enough, you need to set the `PYTHONHOME` environment variable *before* apache is started, or change `PATH` so the interpreter can be found. On CentOS changing `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` should do the trick, just add:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/opt/anaconda/anaconda3
# alternatively this should also work:
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/anaconda/anaconda3/bin"
```

Or create a symlink to the interpreter in a directory on the path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`...
For reference, an extended explanation why this is needed can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/Rmgj8IcHC18)

Comment: Thank you-- I think it compiled OK against the right library now... But I'm still having (related) problems getting it to work: see my edit. Is it obvious to you what's wrong?

Comment: @xnx - tried to answer your new question, hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you -- That must have been it! I still have some permissions issues to work out, but I think I can take it from here. I'm sure your answer will be useful to other people too.