# Why can't my mod_wsgi module find "libpython3.7m.so.1.0" even though it exists?

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I'm using CentOS 7, Apache 2.4 with Python 3.7 band mod_wsgi 4.6.5.  I'm trying to install mod_wsgi with Apache.  I created the file, /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf, which contains the contents

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

But when I attempt to load Apache, it dies with an error

```
[myuser@server mod_wsgi-4.6.5]$ sudo apachectl configtest
httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[myuser@server mod_wsgi-4.6.5]$ cat /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so

httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython3.7m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have verified this file exists on my file system

```
[myuser@server mod_wsgi-4.6.5]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib
[myuser@server mod_wsgi-4.6.5]$ ls -al /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 13683680 Feb 27 18:01 /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
```

I don't know what else to check to convince my system everything is there.  Any help is appreciated, -

Comment: Have you checked what paths are available to the user running the wsgi process?

Comment: You mean the $PATH variable?

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo ldconfig`?

Comment: Hi @cody, yeah I gave that a whirl but no dice.

Comment: Worth a shot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765414/cant-load-mod-wsgi-compiled-for-python-3 -- suspect it's a PATH issue for the user configured within apache conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never stumbled onto the root cause of this issue but when I added this line

```
LoadFile /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
```

to the top of my /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf file and restarted my server, everything worked fine.

Comment: This worked for me on CentOS thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Is selinux enabled? Check that selinux is not blocking access here:

```
grep "httpd" /var/log/audit/audit.log
```